# Does Umbraco allow non-umbraco subdomains

Tags: umbraco

Hi I am installing Umbraco to the root directory of my website. And also I want to install my wordpress blog to a subfolder in the root directory.

However any request to the subfolder is being intercepted by Umbraco and it is showing that document URL cannot be found. Is there a way to make Umbraco ignore certain subdomains?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can tell Umbraco to ignore certain paths or folders in the web.config.

You need to update the following entry in the appSetting section of the web.config:

```
umbracoReservedPaths
```

Add the subfolder you wish Umbraco to ignore in there.

i.e.

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="/umbraco,/install/,/wordpress/" />
```

There are more details on the Umbraco web.config settings in on [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/webconfig)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Tim, but I already had found the answer through a old blog post by an Umbraco developer. Though this might be useful to others.

Comment: @ganeshran if this is the answer that other people need, then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

it's useful for binding too:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/http-bind/" />
```

~/http-bind/

Thanks Tim Saunders

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `umbracoReservedUrls` to tell umbraco to ignore specific pages:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="/mypages/regular-page.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be set up with in IIS by setting up the blog as a separate application with in the umbraco site.

However if you are trying to make a sub-domain there is no reason why this should be in the same site, I would say it is best to create a separate site with in IIS or purchase another hosting account to host the blog separately